# after trigger click, the next delegate didnt work

Tags: c#, javascript, jquery, model-view-controller

i have this script in my html form

```
<button type="button" id="addUploadFile">Add Document</button>         
<input type="file" id="hiddenOpenFile" name="hiddenOpenFile" style="visibility:hidden;" />

<button type="button" id="button2">test</button>
```

and javascript script on ready function

```
$("#addUploadFile").live('click', function () {
      $('#hiddenOpenFile').trigger('click');
});

$("#hiddenOpenFile").live('change', function (event) {  
     alert(1);   
     $("#addbutton2").trigger('click');
});


$("#addbutton2").live('click', function () {
      alert(2)
});
```

the problem is, on Internet Explore alert(2) didn't show up when i choose any file. It works very good on any other browser.

Comment: is it `addbutton2`? or `button2?` I don't see an `addbutton2` in the HTML.

Comment: sorry, i type the id incorrectly. the second button id is 'addbutton2', but the problem still occured

Comment: As I can remember, problem is that IE (IE8 that works as IE7) does not always work with jQuery selectors correctly. 
Try to use class selector('.') instead of id selector('#'). If it works than problem is with selectors and you could leave usage of class selector or come up with your own selector

Answer (score 1):

You are missing the semicolon.

Try:

```
 alert(2);
```

And you should change addbutton2 to button2. Without this, it wouldn't even run in Chrome. 
The click event which you are triggering does not seem to fire in IE. Using a custom event should fix it. For example:

```
  $("#button2").trigger('gogogo');
```

And then bind to 'gogogo':

```
  $("#button2").on('gogogo', function () {
    alert(2);
  });
```

See this fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/UfRUa/3/

Comment: I just misstyped the id before.<b>it still didnt work on IE.</b> u can try to run the code on ur link. alert(2) still didnt show up.

Comment: What Version of IE are you using?

Comment: I Updated the answer. The click event seems to have cause the trouble in IE.

Answer (score 0):

You should change second button id from `button2` to `addbutton2`
File uploader popup apears, after clicking on addUploadFile button. Choose file and close popup.? In this case hiddenOpenFile's change event will fire and after it addbutton2's click event

It works fine:

```
<html>
<head>
<script src="../libs/jquery/1.4.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
<button type="button" id="addUploadFile">Add Document</button>         
<input type="file" id="hiddenOpenFile" name="hiddenOpenFile" style="visibility:hidden;" />

<button type="button" id="addbutton2">test</button>
<script>
    $("#addUploadFile").live('click', function () {
          $('#hiddenOpenFile').trigger('click');
    });

    $("#hiddenOpenFile").live('change', function (event) {  
         alert(1);   
         $("#addbutton2").trigger('click');
    });


    $("#addbutton2").live('click', function () {
          alert(2);
    });
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

***UPD:***

As I know $.live() does not support the "change" event in IE:

Read comments to document http://docs.jquery.com/Events/live

Try using [livequery](http://docs.jquery.com/Plugins/livequery) instead?

Comment: i think it's because the first click trigger. the second trigger to click didn't recognize anymore. i still dont know the best way to manipulate it